# MongoDB Insert Behavior with Casbah and Scala

Tags: mongodb, scala, casbah

I'm using casbah in Scala to do inserts into MongoDB and not understanding some behavior I'm seeing.

```
val wr = dao.collection.insert(myRecord, dao.defaultWriteConcern)
val error = wr.getCachedLastError
```

Ok, nothing fancy here.  In fact if I insert a document it works great.  My problem is if I go and insert the same document again then my error == null, where I would expect some kind of indication I'm trying to insert a record that already exists.

Is this because my defaultWriteConcern is too "loose", or am I just not understanding the correct behavior?  I'm using casbah 2.5.0.SNAPSHOT.  I was using an older version and I seem to remember it gave me some kind of an error, which is what I would expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't receive an error creating a record with duplicate content unless you're violating a unique index with a field that is duplicated.